# Returning object to caller function inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a strict JavaScript API naming scheme I need to follow, it looks like this:

```
var Items = function() {
    this.items = [];
};

Items.prototype.get() {
    db.items.find(function(err, items) {
        this.items = items;
    });
    return this.items;
}
```

The problem is the async call (db.items.find..) that doesn't have time to finish before the get() method returns an empty this.items..

The client needs to make the calls like this:

```
items = new Items();
console.log(items.get());
```

What's best practice to handle async calls here while still *strictly* following the API naming scheme?

Is there some native way I can let get() wait for a return inside the callback or do I need some kind of async lib for this?

Comment: I'm not clear what the naming scheme has to do with your question, which seems to be more about the async issue. Are you trying to say that you can't change the name or arguments of the `.get()` method (so you can't set it up to use a callback or whatever)?

Comment: @nnnnnn exactly, that's what I'm saying. I need to comply to this naming scheme (not changing name or arguments of .get()) for various reasons.

Comment: You can't make an async call synchronous like that in JavaScript regardless of how *strictly* you need it. While languages like C# have support for making async programming easy-to-read and program, JavaScript has callbacks. (In C#, `Console.Writeline(await items.Get())`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using SilkJS (http://www.silkjs.net/), which is similar to Node in that it is built atop of V8 but it runs in synchronous mode.

This way I managed to keep the given API spec.

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but did you tried returning in the callback?

Comment: @DrakaSAN yes, that's only returning to do the callback caller, which is expected to be void

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Apparently what you are looking for might be possible using wait.for (https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor). I have not used it though, so I am not sure how well it would suit your needs. The method you would need would be `wait.forMethod`.

Previous Answer:

There is no way you can write async code in a synchronous manner. Also, it is not a good idea to mix async and sync methods. You are trying to define a synchronous method `Item.prototype.get`, but inside that you are using an async method `db.items.find`, which makes `Item.prototype.get` an asynchronous function. In order to get this to work you will have to define Item.prototype.get as a proper async function with a callback.

```
Items.prototype.get(fn) {
    db.items.find(function(err, items) {
        return fn(err, items);
    });
}
```

You could then call it as

```
items = new Items();
items.get(function(err, items){
    console.log(items);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I've tried waitfor now, but I can't get it to work with mongoose, see my gist here - https://gist.github.com/Niklas9/6370614. It just outputs 'before' and seem to die at line 13..

Comment: Also, line 20 (wait.launchFiber(test);) is obviously required, as that is what makes the actual call for the program to run function test.. how could I possibly implement that with my API spec ? I want .get() to do the call, not wait.launchFiber()

Comment: I haven't really used wait.for so I can't help you with issues. However, if wait.for doesn't suit you, maybe ES6 generators (http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/how-yield-will-transform-node) will?